# material ui Link onClick event type

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I use typescript, react redux.

In the link of material ui, the type definition of `onClick` event will be an error.

It seems that `React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>` does not match and an error occurs.

```
<Link component="button" onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => {handleClick(event)}}>********LINK********</Link>

    const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLAnchorElement, MouseEvent>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

No error occurs with CSB.

Why am I getting an error?

I would be happy if someone could give me some advice.

■Error（VSCode, ESlint, prettier)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o3qV.png)

[error tooltip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/apxbv.png)

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8egs.png)

■[Error contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DlPB.png)（I'm sorry it's hard to see）

■[CSB](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-meitner-o6kn3?file=/src/App.tsx)

Answer (score 3):

From [Material UI docs example](https://material-ui.com/components/links/#simple-links):

```
event: React.SyntheticEvent
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from "react"
import {Button} from "@mui/material"

<Button onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>)=> setName(e.target.value)}></Button>
```

try this next time, its works for me

Comment: The syntax for your answer appears incorrect

Comment: Kindly me me say out the syntax that you see that is not correct so I can adjust it

Comment: After your edit, it seems correct now

Answer (score -2):

Try using `MouseEvent<any>`. I think that should fix your problem.

Comment: no, it says: TS2315: Type 'MouseEvent' is not generic.